# Colors of all polygons cannot be displayed correctly (overlayed) in ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I'm trying to use the .shp file to do the mapping using ggplot2. Although I got the map, but the colors of all polygons cannot be displayed correctly. The colors of some polygons were buried or overlayed by other polygons. 
I used the following R code to creat the map:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(rgdal)
library(scales)
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)
library(ggsn)
library(raster)
owd=getwd()
sf<-readOGR(dsn=owd,layer="China")
sf@data$id <- rownames(sf@data)
sf.points <- fortify(sf,region='id') 
mapa.df <- left_join(sf.points,sf@data, by="id")
ggplot(mapa.df,aes(x=long, y=lat)) + coord_equal() + geom_polygon(colour="transparent", aes(group=group,fill=gridcode),
           size=0.15,alpha=0.9)+theme_nothing()
```

The picture below is created by the code: some colors of polygons are covered.
[image: The first picture is created by the code: some colors of polygons are covered]

The second picture is the original map: all colors of polygons are plotted correctly.
[image: The second is the original map: all colors of polygons are plotted correctly]

Hope somebody can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: According to ggplot's creator [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles), the hole state of a polygon "is retained, but this information is not used by ggplot2." You may wish to try `geom_polypath` from the [ggpolypath package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpolypath/vignettes/ggpolypath.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks very much. I solved the problem using your suggestion. Thanks again.